# Instance validation error: is not a valid value for Xml deserialization

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-serialization

I am hoping someone can point my in the right direction here, because this error message makes absolutely no sense. I have an enumeration value declared as follows in a VB.NET library.

```
<Serializable()> Public Enum OptionDataType
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("0")> None = 0
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("1")> Option1 = 1
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("2")> Option2 = 2
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("3")> Option3 = 3
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("4")> Option4 = 4
    <Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("5")> Option5 = 5
    Option6 = 6
End Enum
```

When I try deserializing an XML representation of this object, I get an error that says:

```
"Instance validation error: 'None' is not a valid value for OptionDataType."
```

As you can see above, 'None' clearly is a valid value. What makes matters even more frustrating, is this error will only show up for certain XML files. Other files that were serialized the same way and have the 'None' value will deserialize without any issue. I have compared a working file to one that throws the error countless times, and the XML structure is the exact same.

Below is a snippet from the serialized XML.

```
<Key>0</Key>
<OptionType>None</OptionType>
<TypeId>0</TypeId>
```

I suspect that there is a deeper problem, but the CLR is throwing a lying error instead of something useful. Can someone point me in the right direction toward finding out what the actual problem is, or if this is a valid error, explain to me why and what is wrong? Also, for what it is worth, the deserialization happens in a C# library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should post the rest of your code, as some is missing.  Your serialized XML references "OptionType" as the field, but there is no XmlElement declaration on the enumeration type that changes its name.

Look higher up in your code, at the class that has the enum as a property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the XmlEnum attributes are what determines the valid values for serialization purposes. Try changing to the following:

```
<Xml.Serialization.XmlEnum("None")> None = 0
```